# Basic UNITY C# code for point on touch screen to point not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

The code is basic and I want to convert my tap on screen to ray to the point
Error=NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Thanks in advance

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
    {
        rX = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch (0).position);
        Physics.Raycast(rX,out hitX,Mathf.Infinity);
        Debug.DrawRay(rX.origin, rX.direction * 200, Color.cyan);
    }
}
```

Comment: add a better debug trace, check what is Input.GetTouch(0) I guess it is the null guy.

Comment: Input.GetTouch(0) refers to the first tap on screen

Comment: @AnitekMalik Camera.main? I can't see other thing possibly null in the code.

Comment: the null exception is for rX = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch (0).position);

Comment: I reallydont know why

Comment: You want to detect which object is clicked?

Comment: Ya but first I want to know what is wrong in the code

Comment: Did you retag your camera? Make sure it is tagged as MainCamera.

Comment: @ryeMoss Done Yes! It was not tagged as Maincamera.Love you man!

Comment: FYI, there's a [dedicated Stack Exchange for game development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).